# More polite way of saying "don't disturb me"

Tags: phrase-requests, american-english

How can I say "don't disturb me" in more polite way when I am busy

Comment: Don't disturb me, please.

Comment: And if you drop the imperative it is even more polite: I would like not to be disturbed, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question might be slightly better suited for the Interpersonal Skills site (https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/etiquette).

That said, you could try something like "I'm sorry I can't chat right now, I have something I need to focus on. I can get back to you after I'm done." Of course, this is assuming you actually will follow up with the person who interrupted your task!